# Where have the old TensorFlow RNN files gone?

Tags: python, tensorflow

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

I found that below files related with RNN are all gone.

```
tensorflow/tensorflow/models/...
tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py
tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py
```

Seems new `dynamic_rnn` has come up...

I'm a little confused by what happened. Why are these files deleted? Actually I'm analyzing these codes to train a chatbot.

Comment: Maybe a better question for the Computer Science SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Being on Github, all changes will be recorded in commits. Look at the commit history to find where the files were deleted, and you may see a comment as to why that was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a major refactor in the TensorFlow repository, which is causing a few errors and some inconvinience unfortunately. Coming to your questions,

> tensorflow/tensorflow/models/...

All the models have moved to https://github.com/tensorflow/models.

> tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py

This file has been moved to the `legacy_seq2seq`, more specifically to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py.

> tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py

The implementations of the RNN cells have moved to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py.

Comment: Thanks. It helps much.

Comment: The word "legacy" gives me the impression that seq2seq has been superseded. Is this the case?

Comment: @norman_h yes, there's a new seq2seq library in `tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq`. A new tutorial should be released with tf 1.1.